# STL Map: Insert Pair of Objects into Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

I am trying to insert Pair of objects into Map containing number as key and value of the Pair.

This is how I create my pair

```
pair< Object1, Object2 > ObjectPair;
```

and insert values into the pair

```
ObjectPair.first = *Object1;
ObjectPair.second= *Object2;
```

Pair is complete. I'm trying to insert into the Map. How should I do it? I declare my Map with a function object as

```
class Object1Comp
{
public:
    bool operator()(const int x, const int y)
    {
        return x < y;
    }
};

std::map<int, pair<Object1, Object2>, Object1Comp>
```

I believed that I'm doing it wrong it some parts.

Comment: What "parts" do you think is wrong? Why do you think that? And what have you otherwise tried? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your keys are integers in ascending order, you don't need a custom comparator...

Comment: Noted.. How do I enter it into the map?

Comment: @JeJo - Because the STL is not the standard library. You can go over the tag wiki to learn more. Most tagging with STL are in fact asking about the standard library.